# Any way to send message in app without use MFMessageComposeViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Any way to send message (i mean SMS, sorry :D) in app without use MFMessageComposeViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: @"mailto:test@test.com"];

But this will quit your app

Comment: This is the only way if you want the app to run prior to 4.0.